# How to add suffix to a string in a Makefile rule when having multiple targets?

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make, executable, rules

My goal is to have a single Makefile that compiles multiple executables all in the same directory. OBJ contains all the .o files except the mains.o which I plan to add only when compiling the specific executable. The logic is this: calling "make all" will try to build main1 first using OBJ and main1.o, but I don't know how to specify main1.o! I thought of using automatic variable $@ to get the target and append to it the .o extension but it does not work.

```
EXE_ALL = main1 main2 main3
all: $(EXE_ALL)

$(EXE_ALL): $(OBJ) $($@:=.o) # <--- here I don't know how to add the current mains.o?
```

I know that a multiple target should expand to.

```
main1: $(OBJ) main1.o
main2: $(OBJ) main2.o
main3: $(OBJ) main3.o
```

For now it just builds everything but doesn't build the mains.o files, it will build the executables directly (they all work, but I want also the mains.o) like this: main1.cpp OBJ -> main1.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: you cannot use _automatic variables_ in prerequisite lists: they are only available inside the recipe.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html  As the answer says, that's what pattern rules are for.

Comment: Yes, you can. It needs a secondary expansion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve `$@` in a prerequisite list you need to turn on [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
EXE_ALL = main1 main2 main3
OBJ = whatever.o

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXE_ALL)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(EXE_ALL): $(OBJ) $$@.o
        @echo Making $@ from $^

%.o:
        @echo Making $@
```

Output:

```
$ make
Making whatever.o
Making main1.o
Making main1 from whatever.o main1.o
Making main2.o
Making main2 from whatever.o main2.o
Making main3.o
Making main3 from whatever.o main3.o
```

Comment: Thank you! This does it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Static-Pattern-Rules) with a specified target list...

```
EXE_ALL = main1 main2 main3
all: $(EXE_ALL)

$(EXE_ALL): main%: $(OBJ) main%.o
```

The above basically provides the rule...

```
main%: $(OBJ) main%.o
```

but stipulates that the rule is only valid for targets specified in `$(EXE_ALL)`.